# How can I center a label in the middle of a panel in C#?

Tags: c#, alignment, centering

I am trying to make an Icon Generator Application in C#.
I have to panels, one that is in charge of the background colour (Border colour) and the other as foreground colour (Fill colour). I also have a label in the middle of the forgeground colour panel (Fill colour) see screenshots [designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsVX0.png), [application ran for first time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXj1b.png), [changed code using textbox and button (see arrow in screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjNKz.png)

I have tried using tablelayout panels and docking but it doesnt seem to work. I basically want to do what the designer align buttons do but through code.

Any help is greatly appriciated thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to remove all anchors?

Comment: Yes still doesnt work https://i.imgur.com/xyLhJKA.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Label myLabel;
 Panel myPanel;
  int x = (myPanel.Size.Width - myLabel.Size.Width) / 2;
  int y = (myPanel.Size.Height - myLabel.Size.Height)/2;
    label1.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Comment: Changed a bit of my code and now it works all the time